# Using pattern synonyms to abstract implementation of text type

Tags: haskell, pattern-synonyms

Lets say I have:

```
newtype Animal = Animal Text
```

And I want to be able to pattern match on it like so:

```
f :: Animal -> (Bool, Text)
f = \case
  NonHuman s -> (False, s)
  Human -> (True, "human")
```

Basically, I want to interface with Animal as if it was defined like

```
data Animal = Human | NonHuman Text
```

Even though internally it's just a newtype of `Text`.

Note that I want the `NonHuman` pattern match to not match `Animal "human"`.

I don't care too much about `NonHuman` and `Human` being valid in an expression context, indeed `NonHuman` should not be valid in an expression context (at least outside the module it's defined) as `NonHuman "human"` is bad.

I just want to abstract the implementation of this type from it's pattern matching syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you'd do something like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

parse :: Text -> Maybe Text
parse s = case "human" == s of
    True -> Nothing
    False -> Just s

{-# Complete Human, NonHuman #-}
pattern Human <- Animal "human"
-- OR
pattern Human <- (parse -> Nothing)
pattern NonHuman s <- (parse -> Just s)
```

If you did care about making them valid in expression context, the following example shows the two other pattern synonym syntactic forms that would make this possible:

```
pattern Human = Animal "human"
pattern NonHuman s <- (parse -> Just s) where
    NonHuman "human" = error "whoops"
    NonHuman s = Animal s
```

Comment: I'm getting a parse error on the `|`. Are guards in patterns a more recent GHC feature?

Comment: @Clinton Whoops, that's annoying. Still, view patterns can get you there. I'll update in a moment.

Comment: I presume the Haskell compiler you're using right now is the one in you head :) so I've fixed a few syntax issues in your answer, but it works like a charm. Thanks!